# Get latest tag/version from github project

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get the latest version tag of Calico, however if I go to https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/releases, I can see they have `v3.25.0-0.dev`, and the tag marked as "latest" is `v3.22.5`. So far so good, the issues is that when curling their api, the versions I get are even older than those:

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/projectcalico/calicoctl/releases | jq -r '.[].tag_name' | sort -r --version-sort
v3.21.6
v3.21.5
v3.21.4
v3.21.2
v3.21.1
v3.21.0
v3.20.6
v3.20.5
v3.20.4
v3.20.3
v3.20.2
v3.20.1
v3.20.0
v3.19.4
v3.19.3
v3.19.2
v3.19.1
v3.19.0
v3.18.6
v3.18.5
v3.18.4
v3.18.3
v3.18.2
v3.18.1
v3.17.6
v3.17.5
v3.17.4
v3.16.10
v3.16.9
v3.15.5
```

Also, this doesn't work:

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/projectcalico/calicoctl/releases/latest | grep tag_name
  "tag_name": "v3.20.6",
```

Am I doing something wrong, or maybe it is their API that might be outdated?

Comment: eventually this list is so long, that it gets paginated?

Comment: If it was the case, still I would expect the latest versions to be in the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, my bad. The solution was to replace the word `calicoctl` with `calico` in the URL I used with `curl` (I was checking the webpage of one project, and curling another...).